# Flexible editable UITextView in UITableView: won’t show the last line under the keyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a flexible editable UITextView in a UITableViewCell. The complete source code of a simple project can be found at https://github.com/AlexChekanov/TextViewInTableView

Everything works fine. I recalculate the cell height each time the TextView height changes and I scroll the table to the cursor.

```
class TextViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    weak var tableView: UITableView?
    var textViewHeight: CGFloat?

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        textViewHeight = textView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {

        guard let tableView = tableView else { return }

        selfUpdate(in: tableView)
        scrollToCursor()
    }

    func selfUpdate(in tableView: UITableView) {

        // Do nothing if the height wasn't change
        guard textViewHeight != textView.intrinsicContentSize.height else { return }

        textViewHeight = textView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        // Disabling animations gives us our desired behaviour
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        /* These will causes table cell heights to be recaluclated,
         without reloading the entire cell */
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }

    func scrollToCursor() {

        guard let tableView = tableView else { return }

        if let currentCursorPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.end {
            print(currentCursorPosition)

            let caret = textView.caretRect(for: currentCursorPosition)

            print(caret)

            tableView.scrollRectToVisible(caret, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that when I add the last line or several empty lines at the bottom, table view doesn't scroll. But if I add any symbol to this empty line, it scrolls.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
class TextViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    weak var tableView: UITableView?
    var textViewHeight: CGFloat?

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        textViewHeight = textView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {

        guard let tableView = tableView else { return }

        selfUpdate(in: tableView)

        // Here is the trick!
        if textView.textStorage.string.hasSuffix("\n") {
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.scrollToCaret(textView, animated: false)
            })
        } else {
            self.scrollToCaret(textView, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func scrollToCaret(_ textView: UITextView, animated: Bool) {

        guard let tableView = tableView else { return }

        guard let currentCursorPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.end else { return }

        var caret = textView.caretRect(for: currentCursorPosition)
        caret.size.height += textView.textContainerInset.bottom * 2
        tableView.scrollRectToVisible(caret, animated: animated)
    }

    func selfUpdate(in tableView: UITableView) {

        // Do nothing if the height wasn't change
        guard textViewHeight != textView.intrinsicContentSize.height else { return }

        textViewHeight = textView.intrinsicContentSize.height

        // Disabling ansimations gives us our desired behaviour
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        /* These will causes table cell heights to be recaluclated,
         without reloading the entire cell */
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView`'s allow scrolling by default which could possibly be the issue. When the size of the text within the `UITextView` is larger than the `UITextView` itself, it allows you to scroll. This may be conflicting with the `UITableView`'s scrolling. Simply use this to be safe:

```
self.textView.isScrollEnabled = false
self.textView.isEditable = false
```

Comment: You are right that the TextView scrolls itself — I don’t need to scroll the TableView, but your answer doesn’t work unfortunately. And why should I set isEditable to false?

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov You set isEditable to false because when a user taps on that UITextView, it will select that UITextView, allowing a user to edit the text inside, also cancelling out any scrolling of the UITableView

Comment: By the way, I need the TableView scrolling when I have a really long text and I point the cursor at the beginning of the text, then I go back to the end and point the cursor there — in that case without TableView scrolling the keyboard hides the text.

Comment: Scrolling is disabled in the Interface Builder. Without that TextView wouldn’t change the size.